# how to change color of img links which are not square shape when hovering

Tags: html, css, image, hover

i am new to web development ,
my aim is: **when hovering over social media link img it should change color like normal text link does** but instead i am getting box background with color i specified under the img, and my img links are not boxes they are like twitter instgram logos etc... , **The Questions** how i make the img it self color get changed to anyone in hover state and to be like the img border not circular or box , for more understanding i have included picture in hover state the img link of twitter is black by default.

[image: image active hover state of twitter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I believe you can't using images.
- Include it as an SVG, and style using CSS-fill.

**Example**

```css
svg {
  fill: red;
}
svg:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
svg[role="img"]{
  width:25px;
}
img {
  width: 30px;
  color: red;
  fill:purple;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg role="img" fill="purple" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>Facebook icon</title>
    <path d="M23.9981 11.9991C23.9981 5.37216 18.626 0 11.9991 0C5.37216 0 0 5.37216 0 11.9991C0 17.9882 4.38789 22.9522 10.1242 23.8524V15.4676H7.07758V11.9991H10.1242V9.35553C10.1242 6.34826 11.9156 4.68714 14.6564 4.68714C15.9692 4.68714 17.3424 4.92149 17.3424 4.92149V7.87439H15.8294C14.3388 7.87439 13.8739 8.79933 13.8739 9.74824V11.9991H17.2018L16.6698 15.4676H13.8739V23.8524C19.6103 22.9522 23.9981 17.9882 23.9981 11.9991Z" />
  </svg>

  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/develop/icons/facebook.svg" />

</body>
```

Get social media icons in SVG for free from [simpleicons.org](https://simpleicons.org)

Comment: Yes it worked i thought that i have to write the path for svg element then i would rip my hair off since i am new , i download svg icon free ones from  https://www.flaticon.com/

Comment: great. feel free to ask me anything! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to my reputation, so instead of complementing mister nobody's answer I'll create a new answer.

Like mister nobody said it is easier to use an svg.

But in case you absolutely have to use an image, it is possible to use the CSS `filter` property with values such as `brightness()` or `invert()` to manipulate its color.

I like to use it with a black icon to turn it into a white color.

Example:

```html
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simple-icons/simple-icons/develop/icons/facebook.svg" />

<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/62/62945.svg" />

<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/62/62945.svg" />

<img src="https://bradan.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/icon-blue-website-design-development.png" />
```

```css
img {
    width: 40px;
    filter: invert(1);
}

body {
    background: blue;
}
```